# ggplot2 - create different geom_path objects in facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

First I'll say that I am just learning `ggplot2` and this was code I inherited from someone else. I'm using `facet_wrap` to create two graphs side by side. I'm then using `geom_path` to draw a shape in each graph, but I want a different shape in each one. Right now I can only get the same shape in each graph, or both shapes in both graphs. So basically need to do something to one facet but not the other.

This is my truncated code:

```
#variables already defined
square1 <- data.frame(x=c(left, right, right, left, left), 
                y=c(bottom, bottom, top, top, bottom))
square2 <- data.frame(x=c(left2, right2, right2, left2, left2), 
                y=c(bottom2, bottom2, top2, top2, bottom2))

RE <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y))
RE <- RE + geom_point()
RE <- RE + xlab + ylab + ggtitle
RE <- RE + coord_cartesian()
RE <- RE + scale_colour_brewer()
RE <- RE + theme_bw()
RE <- RE + facet_wrap(~ v1 + v2, ncol=2)
RE <- RE + geom_path(aes(x = x, y = y), data = square1) + geom_path(aes(x = x, y = y), data = square2, linetype = 2)
```

Comment: You just need to `rbind()` `square1` and `square2`, make sure they each have the appropriate faceting variables and are in the correct order, and then just use one call to `geom_path`.

Comment: Can you clarify what "appropriate faceting variables" means?

Comment: The variables you facet on need to exist in `square1` and `square2`, in order to designate which facet they go in.

Comment: Sorry but I am still confused. How do I include v1 and v2 in square1 and square2? square1 and square2 are 5*2 data frames that tell geom_path how to connect the dots to make two different squares. The variables I am faceting on are v1 (constant) and v2 (has value of either a or b in my original data). So I want square1 to apply whenever v2 is a and square2 to apply whenever v2 is b.

Comment: You original data frame has variables `v1` and `v2` that designate which rows go in which facets, right? You will combine square1 and square2 into a single data frame as I described above, and then this data frame also needs variables `v1` and `v2` that indicate which facets each row belongs in.