# Recursive indexing error with facet wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two graphics side-by-side using facet_wrap and want to do the following things:

1. draw a square, but a different square in each facet
2. draw a vertical line, but a vertical line in a different location in each facet

I used this link to accomplish #1, but I can't do #2 in combination with that

[ggplot2 - create different geom_path objects in facets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23832847/ggplot2-create-different-geom-path-objects-in-facets)

I created the following data frames

```
square1 = data.frame(x=c(.....),y=c(.....),z=a)
square2 = data.frame(x=c(.....),y=c(.....),z=b)
df1 = rbind(square1,square2) # 10*3 data frame that defines the dimensions of the squares to draw with z taking value of a or b
df2 = data.frame(x=c(..),z=c(a,b)) # 2*2 data frame with z taking value of a or b
```

The below code sets up the facets and all works fine:

```
RE <- ggplot(data, aes())
RE <- RE + geom_point(aes())
RE <- RE + xlab() + ylab() + ggtitle()
RE <- RE + coord_cartesian()
RE <- RE + scale_colour_brewer()
RE <- RE + theme_bw()
RE <- facet_wrap(~ v1 + v2, ncol=2)
```

But running this code results in the following error:

```
RE <- RE + geom_path(aes(x = x, y = y), data = df1)
RE <- RE + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = x), data = df2)
```

> Error in panel$x_scales[[this_panel$SCALE_X]] :    recursive indexing
>   failed at level 4

Note that I can run one or the other lines of code but not both.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. The first qqplot() calls a variable named `data` which doesn't seem to exist anywhere. You are using a `facet_wrap` on variables that don't exist in `df1` or `df2` and you're not even adding it to `RE`, you're over writing it. And you didn't include any test data so we can't even try to run it. If you really want help, you need to make this example reproducible and fix those problems.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought it would be assumed that I had previously defined my data, which has the variables v1 and v2. That facet_wrap line is a typo - should read RE <- RE + facet_wrap(~ v1 + v2, ncol=2)

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided any data so I have created some data following the pattern you provided in your earlier post. Note that the data frame contains `x` and `y` coordinates for the points and the paths; a variable `facet`  to tell ggplot in which panel to draw the points and paths; and a variable `vline` which gives the location of the vertical lines (in the v1 panel, the vline intercept is at x=2; in the v2 panel, the vline intercept is at x=3).

```
library(ggplot2)

square1 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 5, 5, 1, 1), 
               y = c(1, 1, 5, 5, 1), 
               facet = "v1", 
               vline = 2)
square2 <- data.frame(x = c(2, 4, 4, 2, 2), 
               y = c(2, 2, 4, 4, 2), 
               facet = "v2", 
               vline = 3)

df1 = rbind(square1,square2)
df1

ggplot(df1, aes(x, y)) + 
   geom_point(colour = "red", size = 5) +
   geom_path(colour = "red", size = 2) + 
   geom_vline(aes(xintercept = vline),colour = "blue", size = 2) +
   theme_bw() + 
   facet_wrap(~ facet, ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: I was able to reproduce your logic and edit my code to add vline to df1. However the problem still remains. Im thinking part of the issue is that my data for geom_path and geom_vline is not the same as the data for ggplot. The data for ggplot is my original dataset (called "data"), which contains variables v1 and v2. And the data for geom_path and geom_vline is df1, which contains v2. Note that I can continue to execute either line or the other, but not both together.

Comment: On second thought all I had to do was add the other faceting variable to df1 and it all works now. Thanks for your help.